# Rep not being added

Tags: bug, reputation

I recently recieved upvotes on my answers to several questions (Ex. [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270144/it-is-useful-indication-for-questions-and-answers-by-external-and-minor-users) one), but I haven't received any rep, either here or on the main site. It's been more than an hour since the upvotes were made, and I was logged in when I made the answers (you can see on my profile). Why would they not being showing up in my reputation count?

And it's three different answers now, so it's not an isolated problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not a bug. Reputation Score does not change when you get upvotes or downvotes on meta stackoverflow.

All in all reputation doesn't matter on meta stackoverflow.

Comment: Oops, I thought I remembered reading something different.

Comment: Or it might have been from before the split, when MSO was special and MSE didn't exist.

Comment: I think it was, (yes to both questions), I remember getting rep on the old MSO, but I thought that I remembered reading that only normal meta sites, you got rep that was added to your account. It makes more sense that meta rep doesn't count, because of how meta voting works.